# Dispatcher: Can it also move from running to ready?

Tags: operating-system, scheduling

First - I'm not sure if this should belong to superuser?
I am trying to dive deep into how the dispatcher works. Many references state that the dispatcher moves a process from ready state to running state. I am asking - what happens on the rest of the state changes?
- When moving from running to ready (end of time quantum), the context switch needs to be saved. By who?
- When a process is asking for an I\O operation, its state will change to blocked\waiting. Again - who puts him there?

In short, the following image there is only one arrow titled "Dispatch". What about the other arross?
[image]

Comment: 'When moving from running to ready (end of time quantum)' - not necessarily. A thread can preempted at any time if another, higher-priority, thread becomes ready and so needs a core to run it - the OS can stop a running thread to free up a core for that purpose.

Comment: 'its state will change to blocked\waiting. Again - who puts him there?' - OS kernel code.

Comment: 'What about the other arrows?' - what about them?   A state change can happen upon a syscall or hardware interrupt that runs a driver.  That state change may change the set of running threads.  That's all there is, really.

Comment: -OS kernel code puts him there - That is exactly my questions. Is "OS kernel" the dispatcher or the scheduler (or something entirely else)? 
- "what about the other arrows" - I didn't ask why the happen, I asked who takes care of them. Again - scheduler, dispatcher, or something else?